# AOSP Built: Now what?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I do a fair amount of Android build-stuff with a heavily customized fork at the office, but I wanted to go back to the beginning at home and explore it for myself.

I got AOSP and built it... and then ran out of ideas. The emulator is even prebuilt. I figured at least the emulator would be something that'd be a result of my build, but it seems like the Repo workspace isn't even equipped to build the emulator. I can boot the emulator, but is it even using the build?

How else can I play with AOSP? Is there even a substantial unit-test suite that I can browse or run (a quick Web search doesn't make it clear)? Maybe the only way to meaningfully explore AOSP's native services/backend is to write apps?

**I had hoped that, with no risk of bricking my own phone, there'd actually be something more low-level that I can play with, like performing amateur surgery on system services just to learn while laughing maniacally.**

I built it for *aosp_x86_64-eng*. Are there any downsides to this? It's not like I need to flash any hardware.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What now? Try:

1. Removing any and all launchers from the system (the launcher is just one or more apps that respond to intents for launchers and gives the user something to see and touch; this effectively strips any UI... because we can). You can do this either from the UI (under the emulator), using ADB from the host system, using "pm" from the shell, or, better, clip it from the Repo workspace and rebuild.
2. Write an NDK-based app that'll run after bootup is complete. Install this by placing it in /packages/apps in the source-tree and rebuild. Pre-test whether things should work as expected by sideloading from the existing build.
3. Interact with it either from the host system or the shell. At this point, your Android is just a tiny, full-functional Linux system with jails around the apps, IPC (binder), and a bunch of device support.

As for whether the emulator is actually using the images from your build, do an *lsof* on the root emulator PID:

```
~/development/android/master/out/host/linux-x86/bin$ lsof -p 12813 | grep development/android
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() ext4 file system /var/lib/docker/aufs
      Output information may be incomplete.
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  cwd    DIR               8,17       4096 44303281 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  txt    REG               8,17   15027168 44303462 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17    6731464 44303355 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/gles_swiftshader/libGLES_CM.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17    7211320 44303356 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/gles_swiftshader/libGLESv2.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17      47552 44303354 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/gles_swiftshader/libEGL.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17     679560 44303361 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/lib64OpenglRender.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17     482400 44303443 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17     429808 44303441 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17     268448 44303438 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17      20632 44303442 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins/imageformats/libqwbmp.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17      21656 44303440 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17      24568 44303439 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17      28600 44303437 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins/imageformats/libqico.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17      38584 44303436 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins/imageformats/libqicns.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17      46736 44303434 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins/imageformats/libqdds.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17    3666001 44303464 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/resources/resources.rcc
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17    2037120 44303413 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17    5786232 44303373 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17    5811584 44303381 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17    6596968 44303409 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17     523800 44303377 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5DBus.so.5
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17     345976 44303401 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5Svg.so.5
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17    4831936 44303364 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17      28440 44303435 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17     116760 44303446 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins/platforminputcontexts/libibusplatforminputcontextplugin.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea  mem    REG               8,17      10424 44303451 development/android/master/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
qemu-syst 12813 doprea   27r   REG               8,17 2686451712 43785802 development/android/master/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/system-qemu.img
qemu-syst 12813 doprea   28u   REG               8,17     524288 43785809 development/android/master/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/cache.img.qcow2
qemu-syst 12813 doprea   29r   REG               8,17   69206016 43784468 development/android/master/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/cache.img
qemu-syst 12813 doprea   30u   REG               8,17  136642560 43785810 development/android/master/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2
qemu-syst 12813 doprea   31r   REG               8,17 2147483648 43785805 development/android/master/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/userdata-qemu.img
qemu-syst 12813 doprea   32u   REG               8,17     393216 43785811 development/android/master/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/encryptionkey.img.qcow2
qemu-syst 12813 doprea   33r   REG               8,17    1048576 43784447 development/android/master/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/encryptionkey.img
qemu-syst 12813 doprea   34r   REG               8,17  102760448 43785799 development/android/master/out/target/product/generic_x86_64/vendor-qemu.img
```

So, yes. Though the emulator may be prebuilt, it feeds from the current build environment as long as your build environment is loaded.